# How to change text rendering direction in PDFBox 2.0.27

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

It is to my understanding that, when within a text block, the showText() method of PDFBox renders the text from left to right and from down to up.

Is there a way to change that? I'm implementing a functionality that renders multiple lines of text of different font sizes so when writing one line I do not know the height of the line that will come below and it is causing me problems because they overlap.

It would be useful if I can just write some text, set the new current position to the bottom of the written text and write some more text starting from there but rendering it up to down instead of down to up.

Comment: have you tried `newLineAtOffset()` ? Try twice the font size as Y offset.

Comment: `showText` renders from left to right, correct, but it does nothing vertically, it neither goes from bottom to top nor from top to bottom. If you experience a bottom-to-top writing order in your code, some other part of your code causes that. Unfortunately you don't show your pivotal code. Thus, we cannot tell how to change that direction.